# How to clean up menu options in Grub2?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am a complete newbie when  it comes to Linix and Ubuntu.  I have finally figured out how to create a dual boot system that has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on it.  The Windows is on a completely different SD than the Ubuntu.  After running boot-repair so that I can boot into both Windows and Ubuntu correctly, I now have several options in the GRUB2 menu that do not work.  How do I delete these options? Also is there a way to change the names of the Menu Options in GRUB2?

The options that I am trying to delete (shown in the attached image) are:
1) efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi
2) efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
3) Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdc1)

All three of these options do not work.  The other two Windows options both boot Windows.  I had trouble installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 where I wanted Ubuntu to be on a separate SD.

The system now works the way I want it too, I am at the stage now of just wanting to clean it up alittle bit.

Any information would be helpful (if the image doesn't work than please let me know, again I am a newbie at this).

Thank you,
~Dan

/home/daniel/Pictures/2013/03/15/DSCN1058.JPG

Comment: We cannot see an image that lies only on your PC, You need to upload it to some place like [imagebin](http://imagebin.org/) and tell us the URL by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some of an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268276/ubuntu-wont-boot/268335#268335) regarding GRUB I just posted might help you with GRUB and your boot situation.

Please be certain that you actually want those entries removed prior to deleting them form GRUB.